# Is there a program to scan and correct names of many files and avoid errors and failure during copying?

Tags: linux, file-management

It seems that the problem reported in [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1615281/1039759) about Mac and Windows not being able to access some files and folders created in Linux is due to bad characters hidden *somehow* in their names (I mean the bad is not seen, it's a sort of 'phantom': see the commentaries under that question). I personally think that such errors happened during copying, but that the bad results affect less Linux than the rest of the operating systems. See the end of [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1615545/1039759) under linked question about a second event.

Trying to do the copying on a Mac the process was again stopped with an error saying something like some file couldn't be read or written. I guess it's the same type of error.

I have to start all over again and I guess I should do it in Linux, where I have many tools at my disposal and can most easily identify an error when it happens.

I guess a good solution for me would be a program (preferably on Linux or Windows) that would be able to identify and fix those names (and eliminate those 'phantom' characters).